# Move around image like a map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a online map for a game. But I have problems with moving around the map...

This code works only if I set the container (div with map image)
to height: 6000px; and width:6000px;

But I must use height: 100%; width: 100%; to get "background-size: cover;" working to have the map "zoomed out"/"fit to the screen" for the best look imo

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {   
        var 
            clicked,
            clickY
        ;
        $(document).on(
        {
            'mousemove': function(e) {clicked && updateScrollPos(e);},
            'mousedown': function(e)
            {
                clicked = true;
                clickY = e.pageY;
                clickX = e.pageX;
            },
            'mouseup': function()
            {
                clicked = false;
                $('html').css('cursor', 'auto');
            }
        });

        var updateScrollPos = function(e)
        {
            $('html').css('cursor', 'all-scroll');
            $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + (clickY - e.pageY));
            $(window).scrollLeft($(window).scrollLeft() + (clickX - e.pageX));
        }
    });
```

This is currently how it looks: `http://5.231.49.167/map/`
Use "google inspect element" to test out what I mean. (Change the 100%'s to 6000px in #container)

Comment: I won't discover 36kk pixels image in that link, right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you set a 100% height value it take the longitud from the parent container. If the conatiner is the body tag it ajustment to the size of the content it self that could be very samll. You need to set up the size to a specifycally size you can use the window size for example.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to understand you. Could you provide an example code of what you mean?